# php field with live evaluation

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

In a content type I need a field where I can put some php code (returning an array) and where I see the render the result clicking on a 'preview' (in a popup or another tab for example)

A typical content of that field could be

```
$x = mysql_connect(...);
$x = mysql_query("SELECT ...");
$result = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($)) {$result[]=...}
return $result;
```

Editing a new node, I would write this code in that field and click on preview to show the result in a table.

Comment: Does exist a field or a solution to reach that?

Answer (score 0):

To get a version of the loaded node, you should use [node_load](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_load/7)() or [node_load_multiple](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_load_multiple/7)()

To achieve that in a module, you can use the following code (using [db_select](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7)())

```
$nids = db_select("node", "n")
    ->fields("n", array("nid"))
    ->condition("type", "YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE_MACHINE_NAME", "=")
    ->condition("status", 1, "=")
    ->orderBy("created", "DESC")
    ->fetchCol();
$nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);
print_r($nodes); // or use dsm($nodes); if devel module is enabled.
```

This code will get the full loaded version of the nodes returned by the query. You can use them the way you want.

Hope this helps... Muhammad.